# Why i have different push notification on different devices?

Tags: java, android, ios, push-notification, notifications

i need to implement buttons below my push notification

and i have 2 device `Samsung S5` and `Meizu MX5`

notification Meizu looks like this

[image]

all is ok

but notification Samsung looks worse

[image]

here is my code

```
public void With_buttons(View view) {
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("Wonderful music")
            .setContentText("My Awesome Band")
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp, "Previous", resultPendingIntent) // #0
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp, "Pause", resultPendingIntent)  // #1
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp, "Next", resultPendingIntent)     // #2

            .build();

    mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
}
```

what is the case of this bug? i expect to see buttons the same like on Meizu device.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: It will be visible only when that particular notification is first in the list, in your meizu device that notification is 1st in list so it's showing that buttons, in Samsung just clear upper notification, when it comes 1st in list it will collapse and show the buttons too.

Comment: @BhoomitBelani i need add priority?

Comment: yes you're right, try
notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)

Comment: @BhoomitBelani no... unfortunately it isn't work... But i noticed that for meizu even if i have my notification in the end of list it is still have buttons...

Comment: try to use NotificationCompat.Builder and then try this priority thing, might be work